# Eclipse Java Build Path does not find jars when launch with eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, tomcat7, java

hope you can help me out with this problem, i have a web apps(JSF 2.0) in eclipse helios, i have created a class that uses apache.commons.validator because i need to validate a Url and some IPs addresses, everything compiles just find a launch it quite nicely but when it ccame the time to actually use the [UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator
at com.outboundfactory.bean.validator.UrlConverter.getAsObject(UrlConverter.java:34)
at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.BaseRenderer.getConvertedValue(BaseRenderer.java:91)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1023)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:953)
```

So a workaround that i found is to put the jakarta-oro and the apache-commons-validator into tomcat libs directly but thats no a solution either. Does anyone know if there is a special configuration to put the libs in Eclipse.

Here is a shot of how i have configured it
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you're using maven then `mvn eclipse:eclipse` will add in the jars.

Comment: yes i try to add maven now it screw my project i better do it the old fashion way till have time to learn Maven!!

Comment: Maven is a good build system, but it takes time to learn properly and adding it at the last minute will probably not help.

Comment: I ended up learning gradle with a few knowledge of maven and ant you are good to go! :D

Answer (score 0):

you might try to add the external jars directly to the project build path instead of the general java build path.  Right click on the project folder --> Build Path --> configure build path.

Answer (score 0):

In a webapp, 3rd party JAR's needs to be placed in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. No further actions needs to be take place. If it's a *Dynamic Web Project*, Eclipse will take care about them automagically.

Don't forget to undo the mess in build path. Remove the libraries you manually added there as external JARs from local disk file system while they belonged in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.